# Angularjs Table error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am very new to the UI development. I am using the AngularJS. I am trying to print all my values in a table. For that I am using Angularjs table. I have a headers and each header has multiple values. For one header the value will change based on the header. Here is my code.

```html
<div>
 <table datatable="ng"
  class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
  cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Entity Name</th>
    <th>Field Name</th>
    <th>{{headerName}}</th>
    <th>DataType</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr data-ng-repeat="entity in metadata">
    <td>{{ entity.entityName }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.fieldName }}</td>
    <td ng-if="entity.fieldLength != 'undefined'">{{entity.fieldLength}}</td>
    <td ng-if="entity.familyName != 'undefined'">{{entity.familyName}}</td>
    <td><select data-ng-init="dataType = entity.dataTypeList[0]"
     data-ng-model="dataType"
     data-ng-options="dataType for dataType in entity.dataTypeList"
     class="form-control"
     ng-change="onChange(entity.entityName,entity.fieldName,entity.fieldLength,dataType)"></select></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Here if we observe one of the header "{{headerName}}" and this corresponding value will change based on this header. This headerName has two values (Field Length and Family Name). I used "ng-if" for this. Here are the two statements.

```
<td ng-if="entity.fieldLength != 'undefined'">{{entity.fieldLength}}</td>
<td ng-if="entity.familyName != 'undefined'">{{entity.familyName}}</td>
```

But when I execute this code I am getting an extra "td" in the table. Here is the output (Attachment).
[image]

So "FamilyName" are placed under "DataType" td. How can adjust this one. Can any one help me on this.?

Thanks in advance,
Amar.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I exactly follow but Is it possible you have four columns in your header and potentially 5 columns in your actual table? Is this the problem... also what happens when you do the following to check for undefined?

```
<td ng-if="typeof(entity.fieldLength) !== 'undefined'">{{entity.fieldLength}}</td>
<td ng-if="typeof(entity.familyName) !== 'undefined'">{{entity.familyName}}</td>
```

but why not combine the logic like so, so a vaue is shown without the ng-if and the need for two HTML columns?

```
<td>{{entity.fieldLength || entity.familyName}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I applied your suggestion "<td>{{entity.fieldLength || entity.familyName}}</td>" and it worked for me. Thanq very much Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, also if possible you can move that logic into your controller (service,etc) That would make it easier to test. I think the answer above is correct also.